# How to reload a background process?

Tags: process, background-process

I have a python script which I would like to run in the background. So I do this:

```
$ nohup python script.py &
```

If I am frequently making changes to the script, I need to terminate the process and run the script again.

```
$ kill -9 <pid_of_bg_process>
$ nohup python script.py &
```

Is is possible to reload the process without terminating it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer - no.

Long answer: You are actually calling a python interpreter. That interpreter loads the script.py and parses it.

If you change the script it has to reload the file and start from the beginning, since the interpreter has no way to know which part was changed.

Now if your goal is to simply signal python to reload/restart the script, you can wrap it into a shell-script:

```
#!/bin/sh
LINE="python script.py"
stop()
{
  pkill -f "$LINE"
}
clean()
{
  stop
  exit 0
}
trap stop 1
trap clean 9 15
while true
  do
    $LINE &
    wait
done
```

You can now start that shell-script (in background, with nohup, if you like).
If you send a HUP signal to it, it will restart your python process.

If you kill the wrapper process the python script will terminate, too.

I did not test my script - but the idea should be clear.

Comment: I had also planned to create a wrapper script too, since I had a feeling that what I asked might not be possible. But my thought was vague and your script puts me in a good direction. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

you can use kill -USR1 PID or `pidof script.py` also -9 is brutal to terminate the process , try -15 for graceful exit .

Comment: I thought 9 was for SIGTERM and I was wrong. Thank you for pointing it out. 15 was what I intended to use as well.